# Can't pull from github and cant update old TLS on FC19

Tags: ssl, github, fedora, yum

all:
I am maintaining an old FC19 linux server which can't be migrated to a newer OS.
But while on this server, I am attempting to pull some websocket code from git and get this error:

`/usr/bin/go get github.com/raphael/wsc`

`cd .; git clone https://github.com/raphael/wsc /root/ws/src/github.com/raphael/wsc`

```
Cloning into '/root/ws/src/github.com/raphael/wsc'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/raphael/wsc/':
Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version.
package github.com/raphael/wsc: exit status 128
```

I looked into some other stackoverflow answers and the common answer was:
"This is due to old version of TLS, upgrade using yum:
yum update -y nss libcurl curl openssl"

But when I do the yum update, it says everything is up-to-date.
What else do I need to do?

```
yum install nss
Package nss-3.17.2-1.fc19.i686 already installed and latest version
yum install curl
Package curl-7.29.0-27.fc19.i686 already installed and latest version
yum install libcurl
Package libcurl-7.29.0-27.fc19.i686 already installed and latest version
yum install openssl
Package 1:openssl-1.0.1e-40.fc19.i686 already installed and latest version
```

Thanks for any help and insight.

Answer (score 1):

Some time back, GitHub and most other sites dropped support for TLS before version 1.2.  TLS versions before 1.2 have a whole host of security issues, which led to [this series of Internet-Drafts](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-oldversions-deprecate-09) (formerly known as the tls-oldversions-diediedie drafts, and for good reason).

This is not only required just for good security practices, but because anyone who takes credit cards, deals with financial data, or is subject to most compliance regulations has to drop support for old TLS versions.  Therefore, almost no sites on the Internet today accept old versions of TLS.

In your case, you're trying to use an obsolete operating system without security support, and so you're stuck with a TLS library that doesn't support TLS 1.2.  Therefore, anything using libcurl, like Git, is just not going to work.

You can try using SSH to clone instead of HTTPS, and that will probably work.  Note that it will not work forever, since GitHub uses RSA keys and will probably disable legacy SHA-1 signatures at some point for security reasons, and your version of OpenSSH does not support the more secure SHA-2 signatures.  You may need to tell Go to always use SSH by doing something like this:

```
$ git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

To avoid your machine being compromised and therefore being a hazard to the Internet, I strongly encourage upgrading your machine (or disconnecting it) at your earliest convenience.  Modern operating systems don't have this problem and are fully functional with TLS and SSH.

Comment: This answer if more of a justification for GitHub forcing me to use a different protocol than it is an answer to my question.

Comment: Most major sites require TLS 1.2 because older versions are insecure.  This is not just GitHub; it's over half of the top 200K sites on the Internet and all of them that take credit cards.  You're asking how to use an insecure operating system to interoperate with the rest of the Internet, and I've offered you a workaround, which is to use SSH.